# Get Filename of Url

Tags: apache-flex, url, flex3

In Flex 3, i have a string like

```
var s:String = "http://www.abc.com/dump/one.htm#figure1"
//Want to parse this string and get the filename one.htm
```

i am a newbie in flex, tries to search it on google, but not get any solution.

Comment: i don't want to use string function to find and split. because it may break in future.

Comment: What do you mean "break"? Can you provide an example? Using split is very easy in this case, just split by "/" and parse the last array element.

Comment: i mean the url could be anything which is a possible url, but this function would take care of all cases.

Comment: i am basically a .net guy, normally we have classes for parsing such normal things. i.e. URL, Email, File Path etc. i gauss something like this should be availabe in flex also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s:String = "http://www.abc.com/dump/one.htm#figure1"
var arr:Array=s.split("/");
var s2:String = arr[arr.length-1];
var s3 = s2.split("#")[0];
var s4 = s3.split("?")[0];
//s4 is the string you need.
//no matter what u try, this code will never break.
```

Try this out and let us know.

Comment: You should also split at a "?" :) in this case, it will work, but when sending a querystring in your url, this code will break if you do not split at a "?" aswell :)

Comment: there could be various cases: if abc.com

Comment: in this case it will return abc.com as the answer.

Comment: +1 just add in at the end s3 = s3.split("?")[0]; and that should do it

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful for you:
http://flashascript.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/parsing-url-string-with-regular-expressions-regexp-in-actionscript-3/

```
var fileWithExtension:RegExp = /(?<=\/)(\w+)((\.\w+(?=\?))|(\.\w+)$)/g;
trace("file name with extension =", url.match(fileWithExtension));
// file name with extension = fileName.fileExtension
```

URI syntax:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax